# Subclassed form Shown event usage

Tags: c#, winforms, events, inheritance, overloading

I am a c# novice, basically a DBA.

I've subclassed a form, works fine. Added some own functions that can be called.

But now I would like to handle something that on the normal form is handled in the Shown event.

How can I create this in my class, I've been reading a bit about overide but can't find how would I do it.

Some of my forms that will now inherit from my own class already have a Shown event, other don't ..

Answer (score 1):

You should override the OnShown method, instead of adding a handler for the Shown event:

```
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnShown(e);

    // Your code here...
}
```